# Blocking information on my iPad from other people

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I recently purchased an iPad that I allow my employees to have access to for Spotify, Sirius, etc. but not my email, texts and personal files.  I used my Apple ID setup the iPad so now they can see my personal info.

Is there a way to hide my personal info?  Or can I create another Apple ID and still keep my old one.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could solve this with turning your iPad into a managed device and configuring it from your Mac/PC. For a single device this may be overkill though, I would just restore the iPad to factory settings and set it up with a new AppleID specific for that device.

Comment: Managed device software can be configured to prevent the user from doing certain things. The user has full access to all the apps available.  That includes apple mail, if allowed on the device.  Another user would have all the same "rights" as the real owner.  There is special software for school which allows for shared users. The optimal word is for schools only.

Comment: Using MDM to prevent access to Mail, Messages etc. would actually solve the problem the OP has.

Comment: You would have to reconfigure the device from the mdm everytime you wanted to had over the device to the other user.  You would have to reconfigure back when you used it.  Gets old, I'd say.

Comment: @historystamp According to the text in the question the OP wants their employees to access Spotify, Sirius and such, probably with a shared account. I don't see any mention of using this device for mail.

Comment: "but not my email, texts and personal files." and didn't your first comment mention mail?

Comment: During the mdm reconfiguration, I suspect the mdm would delete the non-cofigured apps.  So there goes the owners data.

Comment: @historystamp If you set up a new iPad with your existing AppleID you automatically get Mail etc configured to access your mail etc. The OP seems to only want to use this iPad as a shared device to access Spotify etc, without giving anybody access to their (the OPs) iCloud mail etc. If setting up MDM would result in a redownload of Spotify they probably don't care. But as I wrote: Setting it up again with a new AppleID might be easier for a single device.

Answer (score -2):

The iPad is a single user system. I think the simplest solution is to buy the $325 iPad for others to use.  Be sure to keeps the receipts for all iDevices.

edit:  Guided access may be what you are looking for.  It allows you to temporarially  lock the device to one app.  You need to enter a password to get out of guided access. Download some other web browser.  Lock the device to that web browser.

To start Guided Access:

```
Launch the Settings App.
Go to General and choose Accessibility.
Turn Guided Access On.
Set a passcode.
Launch the app you want lock the device into.
Triple-click the Home button.
You can choose to disable touch or motion in addition to disabling the Home and volume buttons.
Tap the Start button.
```

https://learninginhand.com/blog/limit-an-ios-device-to-running-a-single-app.html

You could do all your working in one of these all-in-one apps.

All in one Applications that emphasize security
Good Collaboration Suite
"Secure mobile app-to-app collaboration.

The Good Collaboration Suite includes Good for Enterprise, Good Share and Good Connect secure mobile apps, simplifying access to email, calendar, contacts, tasks, instant messaging, browsing and document sharing. These apps are built using Good’s next-gen containerization   that includes secure data sharing between any Good secured app as well as app-level encryption independent of the device used."
http://www1.good.com/applications/

Quip -- General all-in-on App
"Quip is a modern word processor that enables you to create beautiful documents on any device, including the iPad, iPhone, and the desktop. It combines documents and messages into a single chat-like “thread” of updates — making collaboration easy."
https://itunes.apple.com/app/quip/id647922896

MobileIron's Docs@Work
" content administrators can proactively push important content to a user's device. All content is securely stored, synchronized and available for offline viewing."
https://www.mobileiron.com/en/node/1050

Comment: How does this apply to the problem described in the question? The solutions you recommend are for accessing company data from iDevicds. What the OP is looking for is setting up an iPad for shared use (including access to Spotify) while preventing access to his private data.

Comment: Did you check out what these All-in-one-Applications do?  The All-in-one-Applications provided password protection to the app and it's data. That way if the poster confides his or her private activity to the All-in-one-Application that way other uses will not be able to see the very private stuff.  It's not perfect.

Comment: I'm fully aware of what these All-in-one apps do, I'm using one of them to access my business email and stuff. But how do these apps prevent access to the AppleID/iCloud account which was used to install the iPad, and to any iMessage/Facetime call/email directed towards said AppleID?

Comment: Poster's requirements: "but not my email, texts and personal files."  I did say the poster would have to limit themselves to was as in the all-in-one app.  I did say I recommend the post spend $325 to get another iPad.

Comment: "I used my Apple ID setup the iPad so now they can see my personal info"  You could log out of this appleid before turning it over. You could detach your apple id from a credit card.  It's not prefect, but if the poster insists.

Comment: I assume the OP has other devices to access his data so he doesn't need *this* iPad for any for this. Simply logging out of iCloud might work as well of course, and be easier than anything else.